# std::sort on container of pointers

Tags: c++, performance, sorting, pointers, dereference

I want to explore the performance differences for multiple dereferencing of data inside a vector of new-ly allocated structs (or classes).

```
struct Foo
{
    int val;
    // some variables
}

std::vector<Foo*> vectorOfFoo;

// Foo objects are new-ed and pushed in vectorOfFoo
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
   Foo *f = new Foo;
   vectorOfFoo.push_back(f);
}
```

In the parts of the code where I iterate over vector I would like to enhance locality of reference through the many iterator derefencing, for example I have very often to perform a double nested loop

```
for (vector<Foo*>::iterator iter1 = vectorOfFoo.begin(); iter!=vectorOfFoo.end(); ++iter1)
{
   int somevalue  = (*iter)->value;

}
```

Obviously if the pointers inside the vectorOfFoo are very far, I think locality of reference is somewhat lost.

What about the performance if before the loop I sort the vector before iterating on it? Should I have better performance in repeated dereferencings?

Am I ensured that consecutive  ´new´  allocates pointer which are close in the memory layout?

Comment: Sorry, but what is the question again? Have you profiled?

Comment: I want to know if is generally better to have a array of pointer which are consecutive in the memory layout to iterate on or not.

Comment: The pointers will necessarily be consecutive in memory, as that's guaranteed by the vector.

Comment: Sorting could help in a rare few instances. In those cases, however, you'll probably be able to do much better by taking more control over how your data is actually allocated.

Comment: @linello: "or not"? That's the alternative? OK, then I'd go for "not" because then literally everything else in the world is in the pot, including such ridiculously easy enterprises as knitting.

Comment: If you are not using polymorphism there is no need to make a vector of pointers and you can make a vector of Foo. All items in the vector will be in sequential memory addresses. It should be noted that these are likely virtual addresses and only the operating system or memory management unit of the CPU/chipset will have any idea how the virtual addresses map to physical memory. And even at that the struct would need careful design to make any real use of locality and caching, as I recall RAM is usually read in 64 bytes lines.(which match cache lines)

Answer (score 2):

Just to answer your last question: no, there is no guarantee whatsoever where new allocates memory. The allocations can be distributed throughout the memory. Depending on the current fragmentation of the memory you may be lucky that they are sometimes close to each other but no guarantee is - or, actually, can be - given.

Comment: So you say that sorting is unuseful in this case? It's only a question of luck where new decide to allocate the memory? In fact from some experiments, I don't find a clear behaviour.

Comment: The standard certainly make no requirement about the relative location of memory allocated from different calls to `operator new()`. Practically it typically returns the first chunk it finds in its fre list which is big enough (but not too big). You can create a custom allocator and allocate using this for better control, at least with C++ 2011.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to improve the locality of reference for your objects then you should look into Pool Allocation.

But that's pointless without profiling.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on many factors.

First, it depends on how your objects that are being pointed to from the vector were allocated. If they were allocated on different pages then you cannot help it but fix the allocation part and/or try to use software prefetching.

You can generally check what virtual addresses malloc gives out, but as a part of the larger program the result of separate allocations is not deterministic. So if you want to control the allocation, you have to do it smarter.

In case of NUMA system, you have to make sure that the memory you are accessing is allocated from the physical memory of the node on which your process is running. Otherwise, no matter what you do, the memory will be coming from the other node and you cannot do much in that case except transfer you program back to its "home" node.

You have to check the stride that is needed in order to jump from one object to another. Pre-fetcher can recognize the stride within 512 byte window. If the stride is greater, you are talking about a random memory access from the pre-fetcher point of view. Then it will shut off not to evict your data from the cache, and the best you can do there is to try and use software prefetching. Which may or may not help (always test it).

So if sorting the vector of pointers makes the objects pointed by them continuously placed one after another with a relatively small stride - then yes, you will improve the memory access speed by making it more friendly for the prefetch hardware.

You also have to make sure that sorting that vector doesn't result in a worse gain/lose ratio.

On a side note, depending on how you use each element, you may want to allocate them all at once and/or split those objects into different smaller structures and iterate over smaller data chunks.

At any rate, you absolutely must measure the performance of the whole application before and after your changes. These sort of optimizations is a tricky business and things can get worse even though in theory the performance should have been improved. There are many tools that can be used to help you profile the memory access. For example, cachegrind. Intel's VTune does the same. And many other tools. So don't guess, experiment and verify the results.